# How do I use the apply function over multiple columns for multiple subsets of data?

Tags: r, subset, apply

I have a data frame (sample below) with 943 columns and 500 rows.

```
df <-data.frame(Rep=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), Depth=c("D", "D", "D", "M", "M", "M", "D", "D", "D", "M", "M", "D", "D"), T0= c(-165,-163,-160,-161,-270,165,-163,-160,-161,-270,-181,-231, -230), T0.01= c(458,459,457,342,158,458,459,457,342,158,324,333,320), T0.02=c(-151,-153,-131,-125,-130,-151,-153,-131,-125,-130,-120, -130,-120))
```

I need to get column medians for columns 7:943 in my dataset (all of the columns with numeric data...they also all start with the heading "T" as in T0, T0.01, etc). However, I need the column medians only for specific subsets of rows. The subset would be based on "Rep" and "Depth."  For example, I need a vector of column medians for "Rep 1 at Depth D" and then a vector of column medians for "Rep 1 at Depth M".  I have a total of 24 Reps and 3 depths and would need a vector of medians for all combinations, yielding a total of 3x24=72 vectors.  This would yield a table which is structured something like this (the transposed version would be ok too):

```
 df <-data.frame(Rep=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), Depth=c("D", "M", "S", "D", "M", "S"), T0= c(-163,-160,-161,-270,165, 165), T0.01= c(458,459,457,342,158,458), T0.02=c(-151,-153,-131,-125,-130,-151))

   Rep Depth   T0 T0.01 T0.02
   1     D -163   458  -151
   1     M -160   459  -153
   1     S -161   457  -131
   2     D -270   342  -125
   2     M  165   158  -130
   2     S  165   458  -151
```

Additionally, I need to calculate the variance for all of the cells in columns 7:943 (the "T" columns) for these same subsets of data. This would yield a single number (rather than a vector) for each subset.

I have tried the subset, tapply, grepl functions for all of this, but can't seem to get them to do what I'm going for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the data you supplied:

```
library(dplyr) 

df %>% 
  group_by(Rep, Depth) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(median, var))

    Rep  Depth T0_median T0.01_median T0.02_median      T0_var T0.01_var T0.02_var
  (dbl) (fctr)     (dbl)        (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)
1     1      D    -163.0        458.0       -151.0    6.333333     1.000  148.0000
2     1      M    -215.5        250.0       -127.5 5940.500000 16928.000   12.5000
3     2      D    -161.0        457.0       -131.0    2.333333  4486.333  217.3333
4     2      M     165.0        458.0       -151.0          NA        NA        NA
5     3      D    -230.5        326.5       -125.0    0.500000    84.500   50.0000
6     3      M    -225.5        241.0       -125.0 3960.500000 13778.000   50.0000
```

Or, if you want to make the groupings more descriptive:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(group=paste("Rep",Rep,"at Depth", Depth)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(median, var), matches("^T"))

             group T0_median T0.01_median T0.02_median      T0_var T0.01_var T0.02_var
             (chr)     (dbl)        (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)
1 Rep 1 at Depth D    -163.0        458.0       -151.0    6.333333     1.000  148.0000
2 Rep 1 at Depth M    -215.5        250.0       -127.5 5940.500000 16928.000   12.5000
3 Rep 2 at Depth D    -161.0        457.0       -131.0    2.333333  4486.333  217.3333
4 Rep 2 at Depth M     165.0        458.0       -151.0          NA        NA        NA
5 Rep 3 at Depth D    -230.5        326.5       -125.0    0.500000    84.500   50.0000
6 Rep 3 at Depth M    -225.5        241.0       -125.0 3960.500000 13778.000   50.0000
```

**UPDATE:** So for the variance by group over all data columns, is this what you mean (where the `do` statement might be more complicated than it needs to be):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(group=paste("Rep",Rep,"at Depth", Depth)) %>%
  select(-Rep, -Depth) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(data.frame(variance=var(unlist(.[,sapply(., is.numeric)]))))

             group variance
             (chr)    (dbl)
1 Rep 1 at Depth D 93682.36
2 Rep 1 at Depth M 53501.60
3 Rep 2 at Depth D 81997.03
4 Rep 2 at Depth M 92764.33
5 Rep 3 at Depth D 70057.87
6 Rep 3 at Depth M 51781.50
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is close, though for variance I am looking to do it across the entire subset (all the T's together) rather than on each column in the subset.  This would yield a single number for each subset rather than a vector for each subset.  Therefore, it is fine to me if the variance is not included in the same solution table with the median....I was planning to just have a separate solution vector for it.

Comment: One strange thing on the median table, though is that I seem to be getting an extra column with the heading "X" right before all the T columns start.  It is filled with numerical data. It won't really hinder anything, just thought it was strange since I can't see anything in the code which would have caused it.